# Compress Existing Record in DynamoDB

Tags: c#, .net, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, compression

Hi I'm  facing 400 kb limit with DynamoDB for records of larger size. I'm planning to compress records using Gzip before inserting record to DynamoDB, but the challenge is how to compress the existing records in DynamoDB. Could anyone help me on how to resolve issue with compressing existing record?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Kirk's suggestion of storing it in S3, you may want to consider storing the data in multiple rows in DynamoDB. It's best to separate frequently updated data from infrequently updated data anyway (it reduces the cost of writes).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to read each item, compress it, then write the item back to DynamoDB.

Though I have to ask, why not store and serve these larger items in S3, but with a pointer to the item and any attributes you need to find it, in DynamoDB? That is a far more efficient and cost effective way to do this.